# POST update data to EventBrite API using Guzzle

Tags: php, rest, api, guzzle, eventbrite

I'm able to add Events using post with the following code:

```
//Create client
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/',
]);

$params = [
  'event.name.html' => $this->Name,
  'event.description.html' => $this->Description,
  'event.listed'  => false,
  'event.start.utc'  => $this->StartTime,
  'event.start.timezone'  => 'Europe/London',
  'event.end.utc'  => $this->EndTime,
  'event.end.timezone'  => 'Europe/London',
  'event.currency'  => 'GBP'
];

try {
  //Send new event request
  $res = $client->request('POST', "events/", [
    'query' => ['token' => env('EVENTBRITE_TOKEN', '')],
    'form_params' => $params
  ]);
} catch (GuzzleException $e) {
  return false;
}
```

However when I try to update the event using the ID created in step one and the following code:

```
//Send update event request
$res = $client->request('POST', "events/$this->EventBriteID", [
  'query' => ['token' => env('EVENTBRITE_TOKEN', '')],
  'form_params' => $params
]);
```

It doesn't update the event. The request looks successful. Status 200 is returned a long with the event object, however none of the data is updated. The information stays the same as was submitted when the event was created. What am I doing wrong, I'm finding it hard to debug because the endpoint is returning a 200 status.

The request works fine in Postman, so i'm obviously doing something wrong in Guzzle.

EDIT

As requested output of $response->request()

```
Client {#289 ▼
  -config: array:8 [▼
    "base_uri" => Uri {#298 ▼
      -scheme: "https"
      -userInfo: ""
      -host: "www.eventbriteapi.com"
      -port: null
      -path: "/v3/"
      -query: ""
      -fragment: ""
    }
    "handler" => HandlerStack {#165 ▼
      -handler: StreamHandler {#292 ▼
        -lastHeaders: []
      }
      -stack: array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          0 => Closure {#293 ▼
            class: "GuzzleHttp\Middleware"
            parameters: {▼
              $handler: {▼
                typeHint: "callable"
              }
            }
            file: "/home/user/mysite/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php"
            line: "54 to 69"
          }
          1 => "http_errors"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          0 => Closure {#296 ▼
            class: "GuzzleHttp\Middleware"
            parameters: {▼
              $handler: {▼
                typeHint: "callable"
              }
            }
            file: "/home/user/mysite/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php"
            line: "148 to 150"
          }
          1 => "allow_redirects"
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
          0 => Closure {#295 ▼
            class: "GuzzleHttp\Middleware"
            parameters: {▼
              $handler: {▼
                typeHint: "callable"
              }
            }
            file: "/home/user/mysite/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php"
            line: "27 to 43"
          }
          1 => "cookies"
        ]
        3 => array:2 [▼
          0 => Closure {#286 ▼
            class: "GuzzleHttp\Middleware"
            parameters: {▼
              $handler: {▼
                typeHint: "callable"
              }
            }
            file: "/home/user/mysite/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php"
            line: "216 to 218"
          }
          1 => "prepare_body"
        ]
      ]
      -cached: null
    }
    "allow_redirects" => array:5 [▼
      "max" => 5
      "protocols" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "http"
        1 => "https"
      ]
      "strict" => false
      "referer" => false
      "track_redirects" => false
    ]
    "http_errors" => true
    "decode_content" => true
    "verify" => true
    "cookies" => false
    "headers" => array:1 [▼
      "User-Agent" => "GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 PHP/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Set up logging the HTTP headers on a local server (create a small script), and do the requests against that, then compare the headers (with postman). For example some APIs ignore the queries if the content type is not as expected.

Comment: Please dump and show here all $client->request() parameters

Comment: Have added output of $response->request() above

Comment: Just to be sure - in Postman - are you using "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded" to send parameters? Probably here is nuance...

Comment: What is the response content in both request, try $response->getContents() and check where you are setting EBId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many hours of despair, I finally fixed it. The issue was a missing trailing slash on the endpoint url:

```
$res = $client->request('POST', "events/$this->EventBriteID", []);
```

changed to

```
$res = $client->request('POST', "events/$this->EventBriteID/", []);
```

Now works as expected.

Comment: Ran into this too. I'm somewhat surprised the API's response was mimicking the behavior of GET (200 OK), despite sending as POST, due to lack of trailing slash.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem

Answer (score 1):

A good way to test your token and parameters would be to navigate to [RapidAPI here.](https://rapidapi.com/package/EventbriteAPI/functions/updateEvent?utm_source=Stack%20Overflow&utm_medium=EventbriteAPI_updateEvent) I've linked you directly to the EventbriteAPI updateEvent endpoint. You should go ahead and fill in the parameters and your token into the form and click test. You should see a detailed JSON response. Heres a quick example:

[image]

If everything looks like it has worked properly, click CODE right above the response in the dashboard, sign up, choose PHP from the dropdown, and RapidAPI will provide a php code snippet that you can just copy and paste directly into your code to make the API call. Heres an example of the PHP code snippet that RapidAPI will provide:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use RapidApi\rapidApiConnect;

$rapid = new RapidApiConnect("StackOverflowTest",       "##########################");

$result = $rapid->call('EventbriteAPI', 'updateEvent', [
    'token' => '####################',
    'eventId' => '31082267900',
    'eventName' => 'Ghost Tour Test',
    'eventStartUtc' => '2017-02-20T03:00:00Z',
    'eventStartTimezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'eventEndUtc' => '2017-02-20T06:00:00Z',
    'eventEndTimezone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'eventCurrency' => 'USD',
    'eventDescription' => ''
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It most likely that you should be using the `body` request option for Guzzle rather than `form_params`. Using `form_params` for a request will send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data which is typically *not* what modern APIs expect. In the case of Eventbrite I believe it expects a regular `form-data` encoded request.

Change your Guzzle request to:

```
$res = $client->request('POST', "events/$this->EventBriteID", [
  'query' => ['token' => env('EVENTBRITE_TOKEN', '')],
  'body' => $params
]);
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Using 'form_params' returns: "Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated."

Comment: Can you also try the `json` key?

Comment: No luck with json either